# Dynamically serving files depending on whether they're written to file system

Tags: apache, apache2, crop

Terrible title, but don't really know how to describe the situation too well.
I would like to dynamically resize/crop images. I'm hoping to config my apache to do the following:

- A request for /img/profile.jpg?crop&p=50 is received
- Apache checks if the file /img/profile.c.50.jpg exists
- If it does exist, it serves that up statically without having to hit my php server
- If it doesn't exist, it hits /cropper.php?path=/img/profile.jpg&p=50
- This file then writes the image to file, and serves it
- Request comes in again (see step 1)

I feel like making use of the FilesMatch directive in the .htaccess file could be of us but I really don't know where to start. Any links would be appreciated, or any ideas.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\Personally, I'd delegate this task to a script (maybe using X-Sendfile), rather than a rewrite mess.

Here you go, you may have to tweak your document root and make your "profile" part more general:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "(?:^|&)crop&p=50"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/img/profile)(\.png)$
RewriteCond /your/document/root%1.c.50%2 -f
RewriteRule ^ %1.c.50%2 [L]

# hand over to crop script if the above doesn't match
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/img/profile.png
RewriteRule ^ /cropper.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI}&p=50 [L]
```

**Solution always involving a script:**
(accessed through /img/profiles/... for clarity)

- $1 captures the profile name (in this case assumed to be 'a-z' only
- $2 captures the desired width
- $3 the file extension

Which really simplifies the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/img/profiles/([a-z]+)\.([1-9][0-9]+)\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$ /cropper.php?profile=$1.$3&p=$2 [L]
```

The script would check whether the file exists and either deliver it or generate it first.

**Solution taking the image name from the requested URL:**

(As you mentionned in your comment)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/img/profile)\.([1-9][0-9]+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
RewriteCond /your/document/root%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# hand over to crop script if the above doesn't match
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/img/profile)\.([1-9][0-9]+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
RewriteRule ^ /cropper.php?path=$1.$3&p=$2 [L]
```

which may be rewritten to the following, if the images are stored directly within your document root:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/img/profile)\.([1-9][0-9]+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /cropper.php?path=$1.$3&p=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Actually, on second though, I think the flow would make sense if it *always* referenced a file such as _/img/profile.c.50.jpg_ and then rewrite rule checked if it exists, and then if not, routed it to the cropper.php file. Would that change your logic above drastically?

Comment: See the third one, it doesn't change that much. The second one, always using the PHP script, looks much cleaner and keeps your processing logic all in the same place. Drawback: it'll use more resources.